# Why Dev-C++ does not run my program

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm learning Cpp programming and I'm using Dev-C++ as compiler. I made this example to see how class & objects works in this programming language but the problem is the compiler does not even running the code! Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BuckysClass{
    public: 
        void coolSaying(){
            cout << "Some Sentences" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    BuckysClass buckysObj;
    buckysObj.coolSaying();
    return 0;
}
```

I have saved the file with `.cpp` extension and tried to run it by pressing `Ctrl+F10`.

Please if u know what I'm doing wrong ,let me know I really appreciate that. Thanks in advance...

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Nothing! The command prompt just appears in just 1 second and then disappear... There's no error ,I think the code is correct.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Your code [compiles and runs fine](https://ideone.com/YttAOo). You probably have to create a project first and add the file to it, IDEs don't like files that are not part of a project. Also `Dev-C++` is not a compiler, it is an IDE and compilers don't run code, they just compile it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:
`F9` - compile the source program
`F10` - run the source program

In case if your terminal disappears, you can add `getchar()` before `return 0`. This will make the command prompt wait for your input, and thus you will be able to see the results.

PS: Don't use Dev-C++. It hasn't been updated for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `getchar()` or `system("pause")` before `return 0`

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing! The command prompt just appears in just 1 second and then
>   disappear...

Need to add a `system("PAUSE");` (I'm supposing you are under Windows)

Try this:

```
class BuckysClass{
    public: 
        void coolSaying(){
            cout << "Some Sentences" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    BuckysClass buckysObj;
    buckysObj.coolSaying();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build it first then run it. also you need to add system("pause") before return 0 to pause the screen so you can see the result.

I highly recommand you use either CodeBlocks or Eclipce rather than Dev-C++.